# Non-linear root finding when the Jacobian is almost singular

Tags: nonlinear-equations, condition-number, newton-method, roots

I'm trying to solve a system non linear-equations:
$$
\frac{\partial K(\mathbf{\lambda})}{\partial \lambda_i} - c_i = 0
$$
for $i = 1, \dots, 15$, using Newton's method:
$$
\lambda^{k + 1} = \lambda^k + p^{k+1}
$$
$$
p^{k+1} = - J(\lambda_k)^{-1} \big (\nabla_\lambda K(\lambda_k) - \mathbf{c}\big ).
$$
I know that the Jacobian has to be positive definite in my problem, but in practice it is often quite bad conditioned ( $k(J) \approx 10^{15}$ ). I am perturbing it's eigenvalues but still the algorithm doesn't manage to satisfy the convergence 
criterion:
$$
\bigg |\frac{\partial K(\mathbf{\lambda})}{\partial \lambda_i} - c_i \bigg |= 0
$$
for some of the equations, while others converge quite rapidly. Increasing the number of iterations doesn't change anything.

My supervisor suggested me to use a blocked scheme where, if some of the equations have converged you keep iterating on the equations that have not. 
I don't quite understand how to use Newton's algorithm on a subgroup of equations so I would like to ask if somebody knows how this can be done. Alternatively I would appreciate suggestions on how to deal with this problem.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I must add that I'm using line search with objective function:
$$
f(\lambda) = K(\mathbf{\lambda}) - \mathbf{\lambda}^T \mathbf{c}
$$
which should be fine because it is convex (in theory though because the Hessian is almost singular). I'm checking whether the step is decreasing the objective enough, that is I check:
$$
f(\lambda^k + \alpha p^k) < f(\lambda^k) + \gamma \, \alpha \, (\nabla_\lambda K(\lambda_k) - \mathbf{c}\big )^T p^k 
$$
with $\gamma = 10^{-4}$. If the condition is not true I divide $\alpha$ by 2. Most of the time the condition is true in the first step, so I rarely have to halve the step.

EDIT 2

It seems to be converging if I use a QR decomposition to solve the linear system, without perturbing the eigenvalues of $J$. Not sure whether I should trust the output though!

Comment: Have you tried using a global convergence strategy like line search or trust region methods?

Comment: @Paul Yes, I edited the question to explain what strategy I'm using to decide the step-length.

Comment: Did you implement *sufficient decrease* conditions (armijo's condition)?

Comment: No, if the step decreases the objective by any degree I just accept it.

Comment: That may not be enough to guarantee fast convergence... See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe_conditions), [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/understanding-the-wolfe-conditions-for-an-inexact-line-search), [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/confusion-about-armijo-rule), and [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/line-search-for-newton-method/2491#2491) for more details.

Comment: After your first comment I added a line search that checks for sufficient decrease as in Nocedal and Wright book. I didn't seem to make a difference, the step is accepted but the objective decreases extremely slowly. Now I'll edit the question say exactly what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your jacobian isn't too large, it's a good idea to solve for your newton direction by QR factorization when your jacobian has a large condition number.  It is numerically stable since it breaks the problem into two separate systems with the minimum error amplification factor allowed by the original problem. See [here](http://www-old.math.gatech.edu/academic/courses/core/math2601/Web-notes/3num.pdf) for details.

This enables you to obtain the "best" possible approximation of the newton direction at each step in your algorithm.  If you are using line-searching with backtracking and Armijo's sufficient decrease condition, this *should* guarantee convergence to the true root (assuming your function $f$ is smooth).

Comment: Thank for the link Paul. It's not a first time that I manage to solve a system with the QR, when every other method fails. Now it's time for me to understand why! :)

Comment: No problem.  However, I must also caution that QR factorization has a high computational cost (at least as much as LU factorization).